# Hibernate batch bulk insert

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, batch-insert

I am trying to insert 1000 records using ‘’’Hibernate jdbc batch’’’ and sometime we get unique constraints for one of the records. Is there anyway I can force hibernate to return which row data caused constraints issue?
Whenever constraint issue occurs hibernate return error just ‘’’ db constraints  error’’’

I know I can go back to database and check but looking for some feature of hibernate which logs or return culprit data only.

My backed is oracle.

Comment: Any code that you can share at all alongside the exact output?